# generic Mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1054

I have the fallowing stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get`(IN tb VARCHAR(50), IN id INTEGER)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM tb  WHERE Indx = id;
END//
```

When I call get(user,1) I get the following:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'user' in 'field list'
```

Comment: That's just not going to work. You'll need to use prepared statements if you want to use a dynamic table name. However I don't think that in this case there's a point to having a stored procedure in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a variable as a table name in SQL because it compiles that in when the procedure is compiled. Try using prepared statements:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `get`(IN tb VARCHAR(50), IN id INTEGER)
BEGIN
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', tb, ' WHERE Indx = id');
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END//
```

Note however that this is going to be slower.

Comment: What about SQL injection? Is it safe? I don't see any security measures against it, "tb" can be anything for example a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

can you call it as `get('user',1)` ?

`IN tb VARCHAR(50)` makes it expect a 'string', you are passing something the SQL parser interpretes as the field `user` and that is not know.